# How to find top 10 frequent words?

Tags: r

I have a list of words in the dataset

---

### I find top 10 frequent words using **R base**

> sort(table(words), decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]

### My question: how to get top 10 frequent words using **stringr** function ?

> str_sort(table(words), decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]

The above code does not provide me the expected result. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `str_sort` is for sorting character elements.  It is documented in the `?str_sort`

> Order or sort a character vector.

The output from `table` is a named `vector` of numeric output.  If we are looking for `tidyverse` version, get the `count` and then get the top 10 frequency count with `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(words) %>%
     count(words) %>%
     slice_max(n = 10, order_by = n)
```

---

The main difference is that `sort`ing is different with character elements and numeric counterpart i.e. `str_sort` coerces the numeric output to `character` `class` before doing the sort and this can have different output

```
> str_sort(c(10, 4, 5))
[1] "10" "4"  "5" 
> sort(c(10, 4, 5))
[1]  4  5 10
```

The package `stringr` is not meant for sorting numeric input.  The title in the stringr manual itself suggests

> Simple, Consistent Wrappers for Common String Operations

---

There is an option in `forcats` to do this

```
library(forcats)
fct_count(words, sort = TRUE)$n[1:10]
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need to use stringr functions for this task. My previous code works well but I try to figure out how it works with stringr package

Comment: @Jane But `str_sort` sorts character vector and most of the stringr functions deals with character input whereas your `sort`ing in based on numeric element or `count`

Comment: @Jane I think you are mixing the sorting of character with frequency sorting.  If you want to sort based on the names of `table`, then you may use `tbl1 <- table(words); tbl1[str_order(names(tbl1))][1:10]` and not on frequency

Comment: Yes you are right, it took my much time to figure out. Your logic makes sense. Btw this is HW from Coursera where it says find top frequent words using “stringr” functions

Comment: @Jane Are you sure the question is correct?  Or is it just to make you think about the question and go through all the stringr functions?

Comment: Yes, I checked the question, it says use “stringr” functions for the following questions, this is the only question took much time. Maybe the question is wrong, I will update you with the result. Your logic makes sense.

Comment: @Jane May be there is a mistake.  But if you change it to `forcats` and `fct_count` does what you want

Comment: @jane please checkk the update in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

In this example we make use of the `sort` argument of the `count` function:

```
#example:
mytext = c("This","is","a","test","for","count","of","the","words","The","words","have","been","written","very","randomly","so","that","the","test","can","be","for","checking","the","count")

library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tibble(mytext) %>% 
  group_by(mytext) %>% 
  count(sort = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice_max(n, n=10)
```

```
  mytext       n
   <chr>    <int>
 1 the          3
 2 count        2
 3 for          2
 4 test         2
 5 words        2
 6 a            1
 7 be           1
 8 been         1
 9 can          1
10 checking     1
11 have         1
12 is           1
13 of           1
14 randomly     1
15 so           1
16 that         1
17 The          1
18 This         1
19 very         1
20 written      1
```

We could use `str_count` from `stringr` package:
See here an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(words) %>% 
  mutate(n = str_count(words)) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 10, order_by = n)
```

output:

```
   words           n
   <chr>       <int>
 1 appropriate    11
 2 environment    11
 3 opportunity    11
 4 responsible    11
 5 department     10
 6 difference     10
 7 experience     10
 8 individual     10
 9 particular     10
10 photograph     10
11 television     10
12 understand     10
13 university     10
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code sort the words in terms of their length. 

I want to get the top ten frequent words.

Comment: Ok. will update!

Comment: Thanks, I would like to see your solution too